# Android Camera. С какой камеры сделано фото

Tags: android, камера

Пробую открывать системную камеру через Intent и получаю результат в onActivityResult.
Как можно узнать с какой камеры: фронтальной или задней сделано фото? У ExifInterface такого тега не нашел, больше вариантов нет.